# How do I delete all the relations on my site?

Tags: entities

I want to remove all the relations (created with the [Relation](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) module) on my site because I have replaced them with an entityreference field.

At `/admin/structure/relation`, I can delete the **Relation Types**, but this does not delete the relations belonging to each type.

At `/admin/content/relation`, I can delete the relations individually, but there are 100K relations on this site.

At `/admin/structure/views/view/relations/edit/page`, with the Views Bulk Operations module enabled, I can change the contextual filter **Relation: relation type** to "Display all results for the specified field" for *When the filter value is NOT in the URL* and then add a bulk operation to **delete item** under *Fields*.  This allows me to go to `/relations` and trigger a bulk operation to delete all the relations.

Is there a faster way that doesn't involve customizing views?

Comment: Do you actually need the module still?  Are there any other Relations, or is this truly **all** of them?

Comment: @MPD I'm nearly 100% sure that I have converted all of them to entityreferences, and I'm running this on a dev server first to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to delete relations on a site. Relations are Entities in Drupal.

1. The [Delete All](https://www.drupal.org/project/delete_all) module can help with this process.
2. The [Drush Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity) command set has a delete function which takes a content type I believe.
3. With care you could by hand TRUNCATE the relation table, and destroy and drupal Fields that use relations. (I've done this on a few sites).